# ConditionalCheckFailed in DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

While inserting the entry into the dynamodb table, I am getting the follwing error:

> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ConditionalCheckFailedException:
>   The conditional request failed (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status
>   Code: 400; Error Code: ConditionalCheckFailedException;

This is my Java code for inserting the element:

```
DynamoDBSaveExpression expression = (new DynamoDBSaveExpression()).withExpectedEntry("itemKey", new ExpectedAttributeValue(false));

    try {
        this.mapper.save(itemKeyMapping, expression);
    } catch (Exception var3) {
        this.logger.error("", var3);
        throw var3;
    }
```

itemKeyMapping is an object which has a member variable as itemKey.
So, it should work. The condition is just saying that itemKey should exist, right?

Please let me know if I am doing some mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is here was wrong. Actually, condition above means that insert only when itemKey attribute value in the database does not exist.